# Android GoogleApiClient Builder error

Tags: android, google-api-client

I would like to add ScoreBoard to my game, but I get error like below.
com.google.android.gms:play-services-games version is 11.0.4 and I keep this version in every single place.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.gamesfactory, PID: 11022
                                                              java.lang.VerifyError: com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$Builder
                                                                  at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.createApiClientBuilder(GameHelper.java:270)
                                                                  at com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.setup(GameHelper.java:313)
                                                                  at com.gamesfactory.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:58)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle` file ?